# Nested Serialization using SlugRelatedField

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, api-design

I have a model structure as such:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    # should modifieid be editable?
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    english_name = models.CharField(max_length=SHORT_LENGTH)
    # TODO: make sure chinese characters work!
    chinese_name = models.CharField(max_length=SHORT_LENGTH)
    # student_id = ####

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # store curr time ahead so we don't account for processor cycles
        curr_time = timezone.now()

        # if we don't have an ID, we're brand new!
        if not self.id:
            self.created = curr_time
        self.modified = curr_time
        return super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class SeminarMembership(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student')
    seminar = models.ForeignKey('Seminar', related_name = "memberships")

class Seminar(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField()
    #userID = ############
    title = models.CharField(max_length=LONG_LENGTH)
    #description

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # store curr time ahead so we don't account for processor cycles
        curr_time = timezone.now()

        # if we don't have an ID, we're brand new!
        if not self.id:
            self.created = curr_time
        self.modified = curr_time
        return super(Seminar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Where SeminarMembership is a pivot that establishes Student-Seminar Pairings.

I'm attempting to have DRF serialize an individual Seminar entity such that the JSON response includes all of the students that are registered with that seminar through the pivot. To do this, I retrieve all of the memberships associated with a certain Seminar (many=True):

```
class SeminarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    memberships = SeminarMembershipSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Seminar
        read_only_fields = ('title',)
```

Then, since the Serializer for SeminarMembership is as follows:

```
class SeminarMembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # needs to be read_only?
    student = StudentSerializer(many=False)
    seminar = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SeminarMembership
```

When I modify SeminarSerializer to be the following, I get a "Student object not serializable" error:

```
   class SeminarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        memberships = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='student')
        class Meta:
            model = Seminar
            read_only_fields = ('title',)
```

Theoretically, DRF should recognize that the SlugRelatedField should be serialized using StudentSerializer from the implementation of SeminarMembershipSerializer, and then proceed serialize the Foreign Student Object field for use in the JSON response. But then I run into a "Student object" not JSON serializable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if the only fields that you have in a SeminarMembership are student and seminar, a simple ManyToMany field would be enough. If not, you should use the **through** field for this relationship ([here are the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through))

Then, you must declare a *SeminarSerializer* **AND** a *StudentSerializer* (you don't need membership serializer).

> I'm attempting to have DRF serialize an individual Seminar entity such that the JSON response includes all of the students that are registered with that seminar through the pivot.

To do so, you must put your students in your SeminarSerializer, as such:

```
class SeminarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students = StudentSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Seminar
        read_only_fields = ('students',)
```

Also, I strongly suggest you to use [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) -> TimeStampedModel instead of adding your own created and modified fields. It's really easy to use and it does all the work for you ( so you no longer have to overwrite the save function ).